# What could be the reason for war files not exploding?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, web-applications

War files and not exploding after deploying them to webapps folder.

We are using tomcat 7, below is the process which I followed.

1. stopped the tomcat service
2. deployed the war file
3. started the tomcat service

I have set auto deploy and unpackwars to "True"

below is the server.xml file:

```
  <Host name="x.x.x.x"  appBase="/var/lib/dweb13s2/webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

    <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

  </Host>
```

Comment: Could you please share the configuration in `server.xml` ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MickaëlB i have updated the sever.xml

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation [RemoveUnpackWARs](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/RemoveUnpackWARs#Simpler_deployment_while_Tomcat_is_stopped). Maybe you have not removed the previous directory structure.

> If unpackWARs=true and a WAR is updated while Tomcat is stopped, Tomcat will not realise that the unpacked directory structure is from an older version of the WAR and will continue to use it.